# Can`t find the integral $\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt x\sin(x)}$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt x\sin(x)}$ Im stuck in this problem for about 40 minutes. Any clue how to solve this?

The actual problem is an ODE problem, it is given $x^2y''+xy'+(x^2-1/4)y=0$ and one of the solutions is $y_1(x)=\sin(x)/\sqrt(x)$. So I need to find $v=\int{\frac{e^{-\int{p(x)\,dx}}}{\sin(x)/\sqrt(x)}}\,dx$.

Comment: I state it not for sure, but I strongly suspect that this integral has not a representations in terms of elementary functions

Comment: Ok will try it now.

Comment: You mean $x=t=tan(\pi/2)$? I don`t get it...

Comment: I think you should expect a non-elementary function popping up here (to that integral).

Comment: I didn`t learn non-elementary integration yet (engineering student). Peharps this problem should be approached by other way?

Comment: $p(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ ?

Comment: Don't worry, some mathematicians got stuck on a problem for 300 years. This said, there is no closed form. Even Wolfram Alpha has a hard time.

Answer (score 2):

The solution you have suggests that you let
$$
y(x)=v(x)/\sqrt{x}.
$$
Doing so, your differential equation will turn into
$$
x^{3/2}(v''(x)+v(x))=0.
$$
I'm sure you can take it from there.

(I don't see where you got your integral from, so I cannot help you with that.)

Answer (score 1):

With $x=t^2$ one gets $\displaystyle \int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}\sin x}=2\int \frac{dt}{\sin t^2}=2(-\frac{1}{t}+\frac{t^3}{18}+\frac{t^7}{360}+O(t^9))+C$ .

I think there is no elementary solution.

---

*Note*: $\enspace$ Perhaps you need $\displaystyle \int \frac{dx}{\sin x}=-\ln(\frac{1+\cos x}{\sin x})+C \,\,$ ?